# Approach for finding patterns in daily event data

Tags: correlation, pattern-recognition

I am software engineer but have zero data science background, so apologies for this basic question.

I would like to find correlations between different behaviors of my daily life and different outcomes. Some examples would be:

- How does "amount of screen time" correlate with "time to fall asleep"?
- How does "amount of exercise" correlate with "amount of sleep"
- How does "amount of alcohol" correlate with "amount of REM sleep"
- How does "amount of sunlight exposure" correlate with "daily energy"

[these are basic examples of fairly well known correlations, the goal is to find new surprising correlations]. I would end up capturing as much data as possible on sleep, eating, exercise and any other relevant activities.

- Due to the nature of the data, I imagine the effects of some variables could build up over time. For example, 1 night of bad sleep might not be a big deal but 5 would probably have a large impact on other variables.
- Also, some effects may be caused by a combination of variables. For example, "energy level" could be affected by "amount of food", "amount of sleep" and "amount of exercise"

My current approach is to capture a set of these variables on a daily basis, write a script to put the data into a `pandas` DataFrame. Each day would be a row and each variable would be a column. Then I would use [DataFrame.corr](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) to find pairwise correlations. But this approach is very simple and limiting. It won't be able to find any deep (long period) or complex (multiple variable) patterns.

What other approaches/methods should I consider for this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to [Remove strongly correlated columns from DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282049/remove-strongly-correlated-columns-from-dataframe) & [remove highly correlated ones using pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294983/how-to-calculate-correlation-between-all-columns-and-remove-highly-correlated-on)? for *pairwise correlation* why won't you use PCA methods?